# MySql is not working with wamp server?

Tags: mysql, wamp, wampserver

I have a fresh installation for wamp server 3.0.6 but the state is offline (orange). I recognized that the wampmysql64 is not listed in the services.msc. Additionally, start/resume in the MySql is inactive. 
Note: I'm using win 8

Any suggestions please

Comment: Did you install WAMPServer "As an Administrator" if not uninstall it and then re-install "as Administrator"

Comment: Did you read the pre-install dialog about installing all the required MSVC C/C++ Runtimes? If not check the [Wampserver Forum here](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,138295) for a list of MSVC runtimes required